# How to configure Cucumber JVM + Logging appender?

Tags: java, cucumber, reportportal

I am using 

agent-java-cucumber as agent(and client?) 

maybe i should use reportportal-java as client (trying without success)

logger-java-log4j as logging appender

Now i am getting logs only from ScenarioReporter(scenarios, steps etc.)

[report portal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoB50.jpg)

logger.debug("something") is not visible in RP for me. 

Am I missing something in configuration?

runner

```
package com.example.rp.runner;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        glue = {"com.example.rp.steps"},
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        tags = "@logging",
        plugin = {"com.epam.reportportal.cucumber.ScenarioReporter", "pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}
)
public class CucumberRunner{
}
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.rp</groupId>
    <artifactId>report-portal-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>bintray-epam-reportportal</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/epam/reportportal</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>client-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>agent-java-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>logger-java-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/CucumberRunner.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

project [here](https://github.com/skinner969/example-cucumber-rp)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of example you posted is that you use 2x generation of client and 3x generation of logging appender.
[Here is example of how to configure cucumber client](https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-cucumber)
In order to setup logging, you need to perform the [following steps](https://github.com/reportportal/logger-java-log4j?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration)

Comment: Your link for "following steps" seem broken. Please update it. Better yet, please also add the steps directly into here, to avoid missing information in future.